# virtual appliance resources

Tags: virtualization

I'm fairly new to appliances but have become a big fan of virtualization. Are there any other resources where I can find and download virtual appliances outside of vmware's website? Or do I just need to scour the web looking them? I'm sure there is a central site that lists all the virtual appliances available, if there isn't I'm going to write one.

Comment: +1 for being willing to write one. Please do, it would be great to have a central place to look for VMs that is more search-able and functional than VMware's badly designed Appliance Marketplace. The problem with the other places that are mentioned below is that they are all pushing their own specific stuff, and are not open to other VMs whose only commonality is the fact that they run on VMware.

Comment: thank you for the list everyone, very helpful, my virtualization product of choice is VirtualBox which can also run vmware images very well.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rpath.org/web/

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [JumpBox](http://www.jumpbox.com/archives/category/appliances) and [www.thoughtpolice.co.uk](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/). There's also [chrysaor.info](http://chrysaor.info/) who provide some VmWare images. By the way  i don't think there's a central site collecting availability of VmWare images.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.oszoo.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

I think they are QEMU images, but you should be able to convert them to something usable via VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BitNami stacks](http://bitnami.org/stacks/) for virtual appliances and cloud images of Drupal, Joomla!, Alfresco and dozens of other open source applications